# Cygwin + git + ssh = unusable (high CPU usage due to Antimalware Service Executable)

Tags: windows-10, ssh, git, cygwin, cpu-usage

Operations with `git` take very long time making `git` unusable.

For example, when one does `git pull` (to update local repo to master repo) `Antimalware Service Executable` eats close to 90% of the CPU and it takes too long to complete the `git pull` operation.

---

[image: High CPU usage after git pull]

---

Here are execution time measurements of some other `git` commands:

```
$ git status
...
7m31s

$ git stash save "xxx"
Saved working directory and index state On xxx: xxx
24m26s

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: xxx
23.9s
```

Software versions:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362).

$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.21.0
```

As for `ssh` I have (at least) two `ssh` installed. I do not know yet which one (if any) is used by `git`:

```
$ /bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

What's the problem? How to solve?

UPD. I've already tried to stop (at least temporarily) `Antimalware Service Executable`, but `Windows 10` does not allow to do that even if one has `Administrator` permissions.

Cannot stop Antimalware Service Executable:

[image]

UPD1. As @harrymc has suggested, I've added path to folder to `git` repo via the `Add or remove exclusions` option. The `git` operations have became faster, but `Antimalware Service Executable` is still shows up during `git` operations and eats close to 50% of the CPU. Is this behavior of the `Antimalware Service Executable` considered normal?

[image: High CPU usage after path to git repo was excluded from the ASE]

Comment: Don't use Antimalware?

Comment: @DavidPostill, it seems that Windows 10 uses it by default. I've tried to stop it (see UPD section), but without success till the moment.

Comment: So exclude your git source directory. Windows Defender , go to Settings > Excluded files and locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Antimalware Service Executable (the `MsMpEng.exe`) process is
Windows Defender’s background service and it is always running in the background.
This process enables Windows Defender to monitor potential threats to your
computer and provide real-time protection against malware.

If it fails on some folders, the only solution is to exclude these folders
from real-time protection. Here is how:

- Go to
  *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection >
  Manage settings > Add or remove exclusions*
- Click "Add an exclusion"
- Choose folder and add the Git folder or any other problematic folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Please see my UPD1.

Comment: There are more folders to exclude. Try perhaps [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) run as admin to view the folders used by `MsMpEng.exe`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know about `Process Explorer` (however, have never used it in advanced mode). I've found `MsMpEng.exe` process via `Find => Find Handle or DLL`. How then view the folders used by `MsMpEng.exe`?

Comment: Use menu *View > Show Lower Pane* and *Lower Pane View > Handles*, sort by Type and scroll down to Directory types or perhaps File.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see several folders used by `MsMpEng.exe`. For example `KnownDlls`, `BaseNamedObjects`, etc. And the question is: what should I do with these `folders used by MsMpEng.exe`? (Btw, I've added also `C:\cygwin64\bin` and `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` to the list of exclusions. Just to be sure.)

Comment: Try to exclude these folders. If you can't find the problem folders, you will either have to live with the problem or disable real-time protection (not recommended). There are heavier steps to take ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)), but I'm not sure they are justified. Modern CPUs are multi-core, so one core being used at 100% wouldn't block Windows.